# Different set of data coming from PC and from Arduino connected to modem

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno, uart

I have a modem communicating on RS232, full duplex, serial data, 9600 baud, 8 data bits, no parity bits, and 1 stop bit according the documentation.
When I connect to [Serial port monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsoRA.png) on my PC using the Rx/Tx wires and using serial to USB convertor, it shows the data as it is, in the correct format according the documentation.

I want to connect it with the Arduino Uno, and when I connect I get this [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oS5L.png).

It runs every 15 seconds as supposed but it shows completely different set of bytes.
What can be the issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe there is only a offset of some bits?

Comment: Please show also how you connected the serial cable to the arduino and what is the modem supposed to send..

Comment: Question: Is it possible that your Arduino has TTL UART only ?  ( "The ATmega328 provides UART TTL (5V) serial communication" ) ? You cannot wire RS232 voltage levels directly to a TTL UART RX/TX. You need a RS232 driver, e.g. this shield here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/449